# Get ID of an inserted row in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a forum service ( https://www.orbitrondev.com/forum/ )

When someone creates a new thread it will execute:

```
// Example values
$UserID = 23123;
$ForumID = 1;
$ThreadName = 'Example title';

$sQuery = 'INSERT INTO threads (user_id, board_id, topic, time, lastPostUserId, lastPostTime)
VALUES ("' . $UserID . '", "' . $ForumID . '", "' . $ThreadName . '", "' . $time . '", "' . $UserID . '", "' . $time . '")';
```

The ID is in the column `thread_id`

**Now I have to get the ID (thread_id) of the inserted row.** So I can create a post, and to create a post I need the ID.

I thought about getting the last inserted thread id an adding 1 so I have the id, but SQL looks finer `:P`

How can I know the `thread_id` value for the newly inserted row?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What are using to interface with mysql (`mysql_`, `mysqli_`, PDO)? I think they all have a method to get the last inserted id.

Comment: i'm using "mysqli CLASS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Where `$mysqli` is your connection;

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
$lastid = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Although you should use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/3899908) when inserting data into the database.

**Note: You need to have an auto incremented ID field in the database for this to work.**

---

You have;

```
$oResult = $Database->query($sQuery);
$ThreadID = $oResult->insert_id;
```

which will not work.

You should use the connection to find the **last** inserted ID, like this;

```
$oResult = $Database->query($sQuery);
$ThreadID = $Database->insert_id;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then this should work (that's what will be returned)!!

Comment: @ManueleVaccari Updated my answer. You need to use the database connection, not the result set, to get the last insert ID.

Answer (score 0):

> You can retrieve the most recent AUTO_INCREMENT value with the
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() SQL function or the mysql_insert_id() C API function.
>   These functions are connection-specific, so their return values are
>   not affected by another connection which is also performing inserts

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html

> mysqli::$insert_id -- mysqli_insert_id — Returns the auto generated id
>   used in the last query

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: You mean, I shuold use: "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM threads"?

Comment: Noty realy, click the 2nd link for example. He also meant between the lines u should use prepared statements

Comment: Ouuuu I understand what you mean with the php version :D. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I will try it and leave a comment again if it worked

Comment: i didn't worked, it return "(int) 0" istead of "(int) 4". 4 because it's the fourth thread I created

Comment: Post the code you tried so we can tell you what you did wrong.